# Eventbrite Api event_search call corrupts our venues

Tags: jquery, api, corrupt, eventbrite

We've been using eventbrite for sometime to put up workshops at various venues.

Recently I used a jquery Api lib to retrieve a list of events using the event_search Api. It all seemed to work but I  noticed that our list of events now all had a single default venue.

My collegue, who inputs the events, is sure it is the Api call doing this, although programmatically I cannot see how on earth it can be, since it is only retrieving data not changing anything.

For some time I didn't use the Api, how ever when I did again recently I noticed all the workshop venues were corrupted again. My feeling is just that i happened to look and that they had been like it a while and no one had checked, but the Api and my code is being blamed by my collegue, and it is difficult to explain why this unlikely.

Perhaps I am wrong and it is the Api however. Any comments welcome?

The only other thing I did was to change a workshop from private to public using the same login as my collegue and I wonder if he was editing workshops at the time if this could make a difference.

Any suggestions welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [Eventbrite API event_search](http://developer.eventbrite.com/doc/events/event_search/) docs I agree with your assessment. Doing a GET request for event_search should not change any data, it should only retrieve it.

It is possible that, if you have two people using accounts that can access the same data (Eventbrite has a multi-user access system), one person could be overwriting accidentally.

Without knowing more about the situation, all I can say is if you're certain its a problem with Eventbrite, their [support](http://www.eventbrite.com/contact-us) is normally really responsive.